# Alias on an inner join

Tags: postgresql

I'm attempting to perform a LEFT JOIN on a table to consolidate some data, but I'd like to rename one of the fields I'm joining.

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT email FROM user_email) AS foo ON (user_id = users.user_id)
```

I can select that data using `foo.email`, but I'd like to rename this field in the join so I can reference `foo.user_email`. What's the correct way to perform this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT email as user_email FROM user_email) AS foo ON (user_id = users.user_id)
```